# elasticsearch reindex from remote cluster - null_pointer_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I have some data in index "A_1" of instance "A". I've created an index "B_1" in instance "B", with the same mappings as "A_1".

I'm trying to move data from "A" to "B" by running the following query on "B":

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "remote": {
            "host": "xxxx"
        },
        "index": "A_1",
        "query": {}
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "B_1"
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "null_pointer_exception",
        "reason" : null
      }
    ],
    "type" : "null_pointer_exception",
    "reason" : null
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

I've checked the mappings for the source and destination indexes, and they are similar. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Added logs from instance "B"

> [2021-12-06T00:08:06,545][WARN ][r.suppressed]
> [e883995d0fbec3edf09bc811931ded6f] path: **PATH** params:
> {pretty=true} java.lang.NullPointerException  at
> **PATH**(StringBuilder.java:124)
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**   at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:133)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.prepareRequest(MainClientExec.java:520)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.prepare(MainClientExec.java:146)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.start(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:128)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:141)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.lambda$performRequestAsync$1(RestClient.java:370)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.client.Cancellable.runIfNotCancelled(Cancellable.java:81)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:368)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:357)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.remote.RemoteScrollableHitSource.execute(RemoteScrollableHitSource.java:159)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.remote.RemoteScrollableHitSource.lookupRemoteVersion(RemoteScrollableHitSource.java:88)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.remote.RemoteScrollableHitSource.doStart(RemoteScrollableHitSource.java:80)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.ScrollableHitSource.start(ScrollableHitSource.java:78)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.AbstractAsyncBulkByScrollAction.start(AbstractAsyncBulkByScrollAction.java:245)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.Reindexer.lambda$execute$0(Reindexer.java:114)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.BulkByScrollParallelizationHelper.executeSlicedAction(BulkByScrollParallelizationHelper.java:105)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.Reindexer.execute(Reindexer.java:108)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.TransportReindexAction$1.onResponse(TransportReindexAction.java:68)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.TransportReindexAction$1.onResponse(TransportReindexAction.java:65)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.BulkByScrollParallelizationHelper.initTaskState(BulkByScrollParallelizationHelper.java:142)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.Reindexer.initTask(Reindexer.java:103)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.TransportReindexAction.doExecute(TransportReindexAction.java:65)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.TransportReindexAction.doExecute(TransportReindexAction.java:45)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:180)
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:178)
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:178)
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:178)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:156)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:84)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:86)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.AbstractBaseReindexRestHandler.lambda$doPrepareRequest$0(AbstractBaseReindexRestHandler.java:61)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:115)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:258)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.tryAllHandlers(RestController.java:340)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:191)
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:301)
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
> **AMAZON_INTERNAL**   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:957)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
> at **PATH**(Thread.java:834)

Comment: Can you find something in the ES logs on server A and B ?

Comment: @Val edited the question..i've added the logs from instance "B"

Comment: Enabled _source is required to reindex operation for all documents in the source indices. Do you have disabled _source? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html

Comment: No, I have _source in all my documents on "A_1"

Comment: The AWS guys made it super easy to know what's going wrong (i.e. `AMAZON_INTERNAL`)  Can you remove the empty query maybe (i.e. `"query": {}`)?

Comment: It's not actually empty, I just put it there as a placeholder. It contains an actual query that I've run, and which gives me output.

Comment: Try removing some parts from the process to figure out what exactly is failing: try running local reindex on server A to rule out the networking; then run without a query (but with a size limit) to rule out the query; then with a "bad" query (returning 0 hits) to rule out bad doc data.

Comment: Also, do A and B run the same ES version?